# Java Program (Coin Flip simulation)

Tags: java, class, oop

This is the code for FlipRace program which initiates a race between two coins.  GOAL is a globally declared variable.  Whichever coin reaches GOAL number of heads fastest wins.  Below it is the code for the Coin class.

My problem is that if I put GOAL = 3 , that is whichever coin gets 3 heads fastest wins, it works ok.  When I set GOAL = 4 , still it works ok.  But something weird starts happening once I put GOAL > 4.  Say I put GOAL = 7, still the final result comes only when one coin has registered 4 heads NOT 7.

```
// FlipRace.java
package nisarg;

public class FlipRace {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final int GOAL = 6;
        int count1=0,count2=0;
        Coin myCoin1 = new Coin();
        Coin myCoin2 = new Coin();
        while(count1 < GOAL && count2 < GOAL){
            myCoin1.Flip();
            myCoin2.Flip();
            System.out.print("Coin1 : " +myCoin1 +"\t");
            System.out.println("Coin2 :"+myCoin2);
            count1 = (myCoin1.isHeads())? count1+1 : 0;
            count2 = (myCoin2.isHeads())? count2+1 : 0;
        }
        if(count2 < GOAL) {
            System.out.println("Coin1 wins!!");
        }   else if(count1 < GOAL){
                System.out.println("Coin2 wins!!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Its a tie!!");
        }
    }
}

// Coin.java
package nisarg;
import java.util.Random;

public class Coin {
    private final int HEADS = 1;
    private final int TAILS = 0;
    private int face;

    public Coin(){
        Flip();
    }
    public void Flip(){
        face = (int)(Math.random()*2); 
    }
    public boolean isHeads(){
        return(face == HEADS);
    }
    public String toString(){
        String faceName;
        if(face == HEADS){
            faceName = "H";
        }
        else {
            faceName = "T";
        }
        return faceName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this, `count1 = (myCoin1.isHeads())? count1+1 : 0;` be instead, `count1 += (myCoin1.isHeads())? 1 : 0;`? Otherwise you appear to be setting count1 to 0 if it's not heads, when it should be unchanged.

Comment: Maybe they're racing towards a run of X consecutive heads flips.

Comment: @Wug: ah, quite possible. He doesn't state this, but he might have forgotten to tell us.

Comment: im sorry if i forgot to mention...but whichever coin reaches GOAL number of heads CONSECUTIVELY wins..that is why I am setting count1 and count2 to 0 once a tail arises

Comment: When I run your current code (I didn't even fully go over it) I got that coin 2 won after 6 consecutive Heads. I changed `GOAL` to 7 and it seems to work too. I suggest you clean and rebuild the project, something might have been left from previous versions.

Comment: Also, according to Java naming conventions, please use small letters at the beginning of method names (Flip -> flip).